# turn array into an object and set the object properties as the array values in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have written a function that turns an array into an object n the array values are the properties in the object with a value of true.

In my code below the first part works just as expected. It created an object with properties from the array values and set the object values to true. On my second code example, I am trying to advance it a bit where certain object properties have a different value than true. I am stuck on how to get this to work.

```
var myArray = ['mike', 'jenn', 'fred', 'jonny', 'frank'];

var myFunc = function (array) {
    var myObj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
        myObj[array[i]] = true;
    }
    return myObj;
};


var myFunc = function (array) {
    var myObj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
      if (array[i] = 'jenn') {
        myObj[array[i]] = 'is awesome';
      } else if (array[i] = 'mike') {
        myObj[array[i]] = 'is a rookie';
      } else {
        myObj[array[i]] = 'help';
      }
    }
    return myObj;
};
```

Comment: in javascript `=` is used to assign a value, `==` is used to compare the value and `===` is used to compare value and type. 
I your code you've assigned the value by using single `=`, You need to use a `==` or `===` for comparison

Answer (score 2):

You are using assignment operator, instead of comparison operator. You can fix it like this

```
if (array[i] === 'jenn') {
...
} else if (array[i] === 'mike') {
...
```

Now, you may be wondering why `===` is used instead of `==`, like in most of the languages. The reason is, type type coercion. Even if the data being compared are of different types, `==` will try to convert either of them to the other type and will produce results. But this is not desired in most of the cases.

Whereas, `===` will evaluate the expression to `true` only when the type of the variables is also the same and the value also matches.

So, it is always better to use `===`.

Comment: ur awesome, it must be getting late cause I was doing that but must have had a typo it was breaking so I switched it out, now it works ;)